# Sum of infinite series using integration

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

For a continuous function $f(x)$, we have:
$$\int_a^b{f(x)dx}=\lim_{h \to 0; n \to \infty}h\sum_{r=1}^n{f(a+rh)}$$
where$$h=\frac{b-a}{n}$$

When a=0 and b=1, we have
$$\int_0^1{f(x)dx}=\lim_{h \to 0; n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n{f(\frac{r}{n})}$$

My book says

> More generally we have $$\int_0^k{f(x)dx}=\lim_{h \to 0; n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{kn}{f(\frac{r}{n})}$$

However from the first equation, if we substitute a=0 and b=k we obtain
$$\int_0^k{f(x)dx}=\lim_{h \to 0; n \to \infty}\frac{k}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n{f(\frac{rk}{n})}$$

It appears that they have taken $n=kn$

Can the equation given by my book be proved in any other way?

Comment: This is only true if $f$ is continuous...

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry for missing that.

Comment: Take $a_i = i$ and $b_i = i+1$ for $0 \leqslant i < k$ and add.

Comment: Can you give me some more hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For partitions  $P $ with arbitrarily spaced points, $a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b$, and tags $\xi_r \in [x_{r-1}, x_r$], the Riemann sum is given  by

$$S(P,f) = \sum_{r=1}^n f(\xi_r)(x_r- x_{r-1})$$

If $f$ is Riemann integrable, the sum converges to the integral over $[a,b]$ as the partition is refined, or, equivalently as $\|P\| = \underset{1\leqslant r \leqslant n}\max(x_r - x_{r-1}) \to 0$,  regardless of how the tags are chosen.

With $a=  0$ and $b=k$ where $k>0$ is fixed we can use a uniform partition with $x_r = \frac{rk}{n}$ for $r = 1,2,\ldots, n$ and  tags $\xi_r = x_r$,  and we have

$$\sum_{r=1}^n f(\xi_r)(x_r- x_{r-1}) =\sum_{r=1}^nf\left(\frac{rk}{n}\right)\left(\frac{(r+1)k}{n} - \frac{rk}{n} \right)  = \frac{k}{n}\sum_{r=1}^nf\left(\frac{rk}{n}\right) \\ \underset{n \to \infty}\to \int_0^kf(x) \, dx,$$

since $\|P\| = \frac{k}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Otherwise, if $k$ is a positive integer so that $kn$ is a valid summation index we can also use the partition with $x_r = \frac{r}{n}$ for $r = 1,2,\ldots, kn$ and  tags $\xi_r = x_r$.  We then have

$$\sum_{r=1}^{kn} f(\xi_r)(x_r- x_{r-1}) = \sum_{r=1}^{kn}f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)\left(\frac{r+1}{n} - \frac{r}{n} \right)= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^{kn}f\left(\frac{r}{n}\right) \\ \underset{n \to \infty}\to \int_0^kf(x) \, dx,$$

since $\|P\| = \frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Ive just started to learn definite integrals. I have no idea what a Riemann sum is or what does it mean for a function to be Riemann integrable. I presume that $f(\xi_r)(x_r- x_{r-1})$ denotes that little rectangle's area under the graph $y=f(x)$. So sigma of that is essentially the area under the curve from a to b. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that term is the area of an approximating rectangle.  The spacing of those rectangles need not be the same -- but they can be as in your sums.  The function is Riemann integrable if it is bounded and those sums converge to a limit as the base lengths of the rectangles go to zero.  The important thing is that it does not matter at what point $\xi_r$ on the base you choose to measure the height of the rectangle $f(\xi_r)$ in the process of making those base lengths shrink to $0$.  Any continuous function will have a Riemann integral.

Comment: Also discontinuous functions that are not too discontinuous, for example only discontinuous at a finite or countably infinite number of points.

Comment: Oh! So $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{k}{n}$ are also good approximations of the base of the rectangle. Taking the base size to be uniform everywhere, you define the sum. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!!

Comment: Exactly.  You could use $kn$ rectangles of width $1/n$ or $n$ rectangles of width $k/n$ and they both approximate the area over the interval from $0$ to $k$.  As $n$ goes to $\infty$ both area sums must converge to the integral.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again!

Comment: You’re welcome.